# Link preview on page load using jQuery Preview Plugin(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have use [jQuery Preview Plugin](https://github.com/embedly/jquery-preview) for Link Preview on Github. It works smoothly when I enter or paste a URL in the input, But could it be possible for the links which are loaded from database while page loading/refreshing? I tried the below jQuery code but it isn't working. I'm using it in angularjs. Here is my markup.

```
<div class="post-feeds-block" data-ng-init="init()" >
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" >
            <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="feeds in postfeeds">
                <div id="collapse{{feeds.p_id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" ng-class="{in: feeds.expanded}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading{{feeds.p_id}}">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p data-ng-bind-html-unsafe="feeds.description" id="content{{feeds.p_id}}"></p>

                        <!-- Links section -->
                        <div class="attached-feeds" ng-show="feeds.weblink">
                            <div>
                                <a href="{{feeds.weblink}}" id="weblink-{{feeds.p_id}}" class="weblink"></a>
                                <input class="url_load" type="text" value="{{feeds.weblink}}" style="display:none;"/>

                                <div class="selector-wrapper" id="{{feeds.p_id}}"></div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="title-icon">
                                <span></span>
                                <a class="edit" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                                <span></span>
                                <a class="delete" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                                <span></span>
                                <a class="drag" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Links section -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


/* Javascript */

    window.onload = function(){
        setTimeout(loadPreview(), 1000);
    }
    function loadPreview(){    
        $(".url_load").each(function(){        
            $(this).preview({
                key:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                render: function(obj){
                    $(this).parent().find('.selector-wrapper').html(obj);
                }
            });

        });
    };
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Post your markup, also post the code responsible for loading links from the DB. The problem you're having is with some code/mark-up we can't see.

Comment: Anything else want please tell me.

Comment: Anybody can help me out this ?